# How to add a custom event to a NativeScript UI plugin

Tags: plugins, nativescript

What is required to define a custom event for a UI plugin in NativeScript?

What I'm trying to achieve is to trigger a `foo` event that works similar to the `tap` event on a `Button` and can be hooked into as follows:

```xml
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd"
      xmlns:fooplugin="nativescript-foo-plugin">
  <StackLayout>
    <Button text="Tap Me!" tap="{{ onTap }}" />
    <fooplugin:FooPlugin foo="{{ onFoo }}" />
  </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

What I've done essentially boils down to calling the `notify` function with the `eventName` value of `foo` from within the plugin code (ignoring memory leak considerations):

```js
import * as view from 'ui/core/view';

export class FooPlugin extends view.View {
  constructor() {
    super();

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.notify({
        eventName: 'foo',
        object: this,
      });

      // also tried this._emit('foo');
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

Is there something else that I'm missing and that I need to do to make this work?

Comment: you could make new variable as a reference refer to `this` outside the setTimeout method. For example: ``` var that = this; setTimeout(() => { 
      that.notify({
        eventName: 'foo',
        object: that,
      });```. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: I could do that, but since I'm using the ES6 arrow syntax, there is no need for that as the context is taken care of automatically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

create a property `public static fooEvent="foo"` 
the name of the property is important it should be `eventname`+ `Event`  now it should work.

Comment: Well, thank you! I wonder why that isn't documented, or if I somehow missed it in the docs? Sometimes I wish I'd come to StackOverflow sooner.

Comment: yes,it's not documented yet and I struggled with this problem 3 days,finally I found all plugins did this and I tried it and worked :)

Comment: damet garm agha ;)

Comment: @HabibKazemi Thanks! was looking for this high and low, this should be documented !

Answer (score 0):

1. create a property of your Event `public static fooEvent="foo"`. The name is important! It has to be `eventname` + `"Event"`
2. overload the `on`-function in your declaration file `index.d.ts` or `FooPlugin.d.ts`

   `// Needed when on method is overriden.
   on(eventNames: string, callback: (data: EventData) => void, thisArg?: any);`